# Clean and neat way of asking permissions in android, like in this screen. How can I achieve this?

Tags: android

I accidently found this app which asks permission in a very clean way in just one screen with just one button to grant it. Here is the link to the project: https://github.com/karma9874/AndroRAT
Here is a screen:
[image]

I looked all the source code,but I have found nothing related to this.

Comment: What do u mean by clean way ? you can not allow permission by yourself with these Switches  you need to ask permission from the System . And u can ask multiple permission at once .. Is this an App Screen or System Setting Screen ?

Comment: At adding a new Activity to your project Android Studio offers you different Activity models to choose from. Choose Settings Activity.

Comment: I have found the solution, all you have to do  is just decrease you targetSdk version to 22